# Groovy Maven plugin, marking target stub as source directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am using gmavenplus-plugin, below is the configuration details

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After each time maven clean build, intellij's settings gets updated and it maker generated stub as source and test source folders. Ideally goal  removeStubs and removeTestStubs should remove it from source. All examples on internet is based on above configuration only.

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The way IntelliJ hooks into the GMavenPlus (and GMaven) lifecycle was by expecting specific goal names.  [1.6](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/releases/tag/1.6) fixes this by renaming the goals to match IntelliJ's expectations.